# Is it possible to optimally calculate state of items for each day only with database engine?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table that represents state of let's say backpack for given date:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `daily_backpack_state` (
  `backpackId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `size` double(16,4) NOT NULL,
  `ownerId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`backpackId`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The version of mysql is 5.7.37.

For given date range (not greater than 1500 days), e.g `startDate='2022-01-01'` and `endDate=2022-05-01` and owner ids subset e.g. `['first id', 'second id', ...]` I want to receive this kind of an object that represents state for each day that represents total backpacks count and sizes for owners subset

```
{
   data: [
     { date: '2022-01-01', backpacksCount: 2, totalBackpacksSize: 10 },
     { date: '2022-01-02', backpacksCount: 1, totalBackpacksSize: 7 },
     ...
   ]
}
```

Primary key guarantees that there will be at most one entry for the concrete backpack for each day.

Owners and sizes of the backpacks can change in the time.

If backpack was deleted there will be an entry with the field `deleted` set to `true` and this will be the last entry in the table of the backpack (there is no such mechanism like 'undelete').
Deleted backpack in day `x` does not count for this day.

My problem is that entry for backpack will be only present in the table if something changed. For example backpack was created in 2020-12-31, so there will be record:

```
{ backpackId: '123', ownerId: '123', size: 123, date: '2020-12-31', deleted: false }
```

but there will not be entry for next day like:

```
{ backpackId: '123', ownerId: '123', size: 123, date: '2021-01-01', deleted: false }
```

Sample table could be:

```
| backpackId | ownerId | size |    date    | deleted |
|     4      |    3    |   3  | 2020-11-21 |  false. |
|     2      |    1    |   1  | 2020-12-31 |  false. |
|     3      |    3    |   2  | 2020-12-31 |  false. |
|     1      |    1    |   1  | 2021-01-01 |  false. |
|     1      |    2    |   1  | 2021-01-02 |  false. |
|     4      |    3    |   2  | 2021-01-02 |  false. |
|     1      |    2    |   1  | 2021-01-03 |  true.  |
|     4      |    3    |   2  | 2021-01-04 |  true.  |
```

For given `startDate=2021-01-01`, `endDate=2021-01-05` and ownerIds=`[1, 3]` the result should be:

```
{
  data: [
    { date: '2021-01-01', backpacksCount: 4, totalBackpacksSize: 7 }, 
    { date: '2021-01-02', backpacksCount: 3, totalBackpacksSize: 5 },
    { date: '2021-01-03', backpacksCount: 3, totalBackpacksSize: 5 },
    { date: '2021-01-04', backpacksCount: 2, totalBackpacksSize: 3 },
    { date: '2021-01-05', backpacksCount: 2, totalBackpacksSize: 3 },
  ]
}
```

So simple grouping with aggregate functions is not working.
My idea was to create temporary table with entries for each backpack for each day and simply use group by to calculate everything I want, but I think it would be too slow (I have not tried this solution yet).

What should be the best approach to solve this kind of problem? Maybe I should simply load everything to memory and calculate it instead of doing it with the database? Or maybe there exists one beautiful query to easily calculate it?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  does a backpack count on the day it is deleted, or only on previous days?  are there any records for a backpack besides when it was created or when it was deleted?  if so, are there size changes?

Comment: @ysth 5.17.37. It's only count on previous days. I have updated the original question

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to show us some sample data and the desired results. It's best if you show us the edge cases as well as the ordinary cases.

Comment: @O.Jones I have edited the question and added some sample data

Comment: there is no 5.17, pretty sure you mean 5.7.37.

Comment: you want dates included in the results even if there are no changes on that day?  (e.g. 2021-01-05)  if so, it would help to know the maximum number of days that will ever be in the date range.

Comment: @ysth updated the question. Plus yes, you are right with the version :)

Answer (score 0):

To get your results, you will need to sum all the relevant backpacks on each day in your range.  First, find all the relevant backpack ids (using the example owners and date range):

```
select
    backpackId,
    min(case when not deleted and ownerId in (1,3) then date end) earliest_date,
    max(case when deleted then date end) deleted_date
from daily_backpack_state
group by backpackId
having
    earliest_date <= '2021-01-05' and
    (deleted_date is null or deleted_date > '2021-01-01')
```

To find all the dates in your range (this is much easier to do in mysql 8):

```
select '2021-01-01'+interval a+(b+(c+d*7)*7)*7 day report_date
from (select 0 a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) a cross join (select 0 b union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) b cross join (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) c cross join (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) d
having report_date <= '2021-01-05'
```

Now join the dates and backpack ids to all rows in daily_backpack_state for that backpack on or before each date, grouping by backpack and date being reported and getting the most recent state for each backpack for each date (again, that last part is much easier to do in mysql 8) and ignoring ones where that most recent state has the wrong owner or is deleted.

```
select
    backpacks.backpackId,
    report_dates.report_date,
    0+substr(max(concat(dbs.date,size)),11) size,
    0+substr(max(concat(dbs.date,ownerId)),11) ownerId,
    0+substr(max(concat(dbs.date,deleted)),11) deleted
from (
    select '2021-01-01'+interval a+(b+(c+d*7)*7)*7 day report_date
    from (select 0 a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) a cross join (select 0 b union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) b cross join (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) c cross join (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) d
    having report_date <= '2021-01-05'
) report_dates
left join (
    select
        backpackId,
        min(case when not deleted and ownerId in (1,3) then date end) earliest_date,
        max(case when deleted then date end) deleted_date
    from daily_backpack_state
    group by backpackId
    having
        earliest_date <= '2021-01-05' and
        (deleted_date is null or deleted_date > '2021-01-01')
) backpacks on 1
left join daily_backpack_state dbs on dbs.backpackId=backpacks.backpackId and dbs.date <= report_dates.report_date
group by backpacks.backpackId, report_dates.report_date
having backpackId is null or (ownerId in (1,3) and not deleted)
```

Finally, take the results of that and group them by report_date and sum the count and size of backpacks for each date:

```
select
    report_date,
    count(backpackId) backpacksCount,
    coalesce(sum(size),0) totalBackpacksSize
from (
    select
        backpacks.backpackId,
        report_dates.report_date,
        0+substr(max(concat(dbs.date,size)),11) size,
        0+substr(max(concat(dbs.date,ownerId)),11) ownerId,
        0+substr(max(concat(dbs.date,deleted)),11) deleted
    from (
        select '2021-01-01'+interval a+(b+(c+d*7)*7)*7 day report_date
        from (select 0 a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) a cross join (select 0 b union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) b cross join (select 0 c union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) c cross join (select 0 d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6) d
        having report_date <= '2021-01-05'
    ) report_dates
    left join (
        select
            backpackId,
            min(case when not deleted and ownerId in (1,3) then date end) earliest_date,
            max(case when deleted then date end) deleted_date
        from daily_backpack_state
        group by backpackId
        having
            earliest_date <= '2021-01-05' and
            (deleted_date is null or deleted_date > '2021-01-01')
    ) backpacks on 1
    left join daily_backpack_state dbs on dbs.backpackId=backpacks.backpackId and dbs.date <= report_dates.report_date
    group by backpacks.backpackId, report_dates.report_date
    having backpackId is null or (ownerId in (1,3) and not deleted)
) backpack_dates
group by report_date
```